# preg_replace() not replacing with <. Returns failure

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm trying to replace `\u003C` with `<` using `preg_replace` but it returns same input.

here is my preg_replace

```
 preg_replace('/\\\\u003C/','<','name\u003Cname@example.com\u003E');
```

Any Help.

Comment: Why do you put four slashes `\\\\u003C` into the pattern ? Two are enough.

Comment: @Pete_Gore: One pair is needed because you 're in a PHP string literal, the other because you are writing a regex.

Comment: I tested `preg_replace('/\\u003C/','<','name\u003Cname@example.com\u003E');` and I worked well

Comment: This works fine, at it should. Are you sure it's your actual code?

Comment: @Pete_Gore: [I find that hard to believe](https://ideone.com/IKzwhp).

Comment: I tried it with \\\, it works fine.

Comment: @AliGajani: It works with \\\ as well because `\\u` and `\u` in a single-quoted string literal are both translated to `\u`.

Comment: Why would the OP not use `str_replace`?

Comment: for me none of these working it returns `"name\u003Cname@example.com\\u003E"`

Comment: @james: Post your **actual** code. I 've given a link to what you have now, and it works.

Comment: @hjpotter92 I tried but that also not working

Answer (score 1):

If you want to replace a specific string you should use:

```
str_replace("\u003C", "<", "name\u003Cname@example.com\u003E");
```

I think you don't need regex.

Hope it helps.